# OpenGL Water Waves - gradually advance

Tags: opengl, vertex

I want to make a simulation of water drops producing waves, in OpenGL with C++. I calculated the height for each point of my plane grid in the 'Vertex Shader' with this formula:

[image: Wi(x, y, t) = Ai * sin(Do • (x, y) * wi + t * Pi)]

The problem is that I don't know how to generate the waves so they gradually advance.

---

This is what my waves look like:

[image: My waves.]

I want to have one circle at the beginning instead of all of them. The first circle should get bigger, like in the photo.

---

How do I do this?

Comment: Where did you get that formula from?

Comment: http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch01.html

Comment: This article is about endlessly generating waves, not about actually computing realistic physic based ones.

Comment: It looks to me like you have the advancing term in there already: + t*phi is a phase adjustment, which shifts the waves over time (t) at a speed given by the phi coefficient.

Comment: @dominodominica What are x, y and t?

Comment: Please clarify the question - are you looking into simpler procedural geometry solution, OR more complicated physics based one?

Comment: It's a sine wave, by definition that's infinite. To keep it down to a it at a single wave, as you want, you clamp it. Look into Step functions. You'll also want to smooth the edges of the resulting function, and reduce the amplitude as it moves away from the center.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Wave function]

See that `t` there towards the end?

That represents *time.*  Replace it with the system clock time in milliseconds, adjust Phi as necessary (so that the waves move at the desired rate: larger phi value means they'll move more quickly, smaller phi and they've move more slowly, negative and they're converge rather than diverge), and you're done.

Comment: Is that a  麒麟 in your profile pic?

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer It's a dragon.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do something like a physics simulation of the water surface. If you break the surface up into smaller polygons and connect neighboring polys by virtual springs, you can move one in the center and that movement should propagate over time. [Here is an interesting example](http://andrew-hoyer.com/experiments/cloth/) with links to papers on how it works.